# Return statement not working in java?

Tags: java

Hello i'm trying to print a sequence of characters using a method of return type     "String".Below mentioned is the logic .The error which i'm getting is:

```
 prog1.java:34: error: missing return statement
  }
  ^
 1 error
```

Below mentioned is the code.it should print characters ..i'm able to do with type "void"  but i'm not able to do with  return type "int".Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

```
import java.util.*;

class prog1 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        double height;
        double width;
        String fillcharac;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter a value for height");
        height = sc.nextDouble();
        Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter a value for width:");
        width = sc.nextDouble();
        Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter the character value:");
        fillcharac = sc2.next();
        String x = print(height, width, fillcharac);
        System.out.println(x);
    }

    public static String print(double height, double width, String fill) 
    {
        for (double i = 1; i <= height; i++) 
        {
            for (double j = 1; j <= width; j++) 
            {
                return fill;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers.  See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your inner `for` loop should be "building" an string that is returned after the loops have finished.

Perhaps the method should be named `build` instead of `print` as the printing is done later?

Something like:

```
public static String build( double height, double width, String fill ) {
  String result;
  for( double i=1; i<=height; i++) {
    for(double j=1; j<=width; j++) {
      // Build your string here using i, j and fill
      // result = ...
      }
    }
  return result;
  }
```

Then you can do:

```
//  Build the output string
x = build( height, width, fillcharac );

//  Print the output string
System.out.println( x );
```

Comment: i did accordingly however it returned me a symbol that's it!

Comment: You need to modify your question and tell us what you expect to print. Your question is not clear.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing return statement in `print` method . In order to correct it just return some string value for.e.g.

```
public  static  String print( double height,double width, String fill)
{
 for(double i =1;i<=height;i++){
 for(double j=1;j<=width;j++){

  return fill;
  }
 }
    return fill;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to return something in the case that `return fill;` is never executed.  That can happen if `height` or `width` is less than `1`.

In this case, it doesn't make sense to enter a `for` loop (or even 2 loops) if all you're going to do is return `fill`.  If you're going to do something else, add that code in the loop.  Either way, you must add another `return` statement at the bottom of the method to satisfy the compiler, so it knows that something is returned in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

As sol4me said, you are missing the return statement within the print() method. Java is protecting you from having possible executions that would miss the return statement entirely. e.g.

```
print(0, 5, fillcharac);
```

In this case, the outer loop would never execute and the method would immediately exit, but Java would have no idea what the method should return.

As a side note... why have loops if you are just returning on the first iteration? Perhaps a logical error? The height and width parameters have no effect on the execution of the code (assuming they are >=1). The whole print method could be rewritten as:

```
public static String print( String fill)
{
     return fill;
}
```

With a method this simple, there isn't a point to having a method at all.